# Laravel Polymorphic Relations returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relational-database

I've read many posts about this issue but none of them works for me. I have a 'ISA' relationship in my database. A **person** can be either a **Patient** or a **Nurse**:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Patient extends Model
{
    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Person', 'commentable');
    }    
}

class Nurse extends Model
{
    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Person', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

This is my tables and the data inside them:
[image: My database and data inside them]

And this is my Route:

```
Route::get('person', function () {
    $person = Person::find(1)->commentable();
    return json_decode(json_encode($person), true);
});
```

I get an empty array!

Comment: What's the purpose of `json_decode(json_encode($person), true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to access the relationship as a property:

```
$person = Person::find(1)->commentable;
```